# PHP - upload photo to Twitter with PHP

Tags: php, twitter

I can add photo to my twitter with API, and its not working

This is my code, and this code not working

```
<?php

    require ('twit/tmhOAuth.php');
    require ('twit/twitUnti.php');
$tmhOAuth = new tmhOAuth(array(
  'consumer_key'    => 'XXX',
  'consumer_secret' => 'XXX',
  'user_token'      => "XX",
  'user_secret'     => "XXX",
));


$image = "yeah.jpg";

$code = $tmhOAuth->request('POST', 'https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json',
  array(
    'media[]'  => "@{$image}",
    'status'   => "Don't slip up" // Don't give up..
  ),
  true, // use auth
  true  // multipart
);

if ($code == 200) {
  tmhUtilities::pr(json_decode($tmhOAuth->response['response']));
} else {
  tmhUtilities::pr($tmhOAuth->response['response']);
}
?>
```

please help me, thanks

Comment: Why it is not working? Do you have any errors? What is the response?

Comment: dont have error, but not show on my twitter

Comment: What is in `$tmhOAuth->response['headers']` or `$tmhOAuth->response['response']` ?

Comment: i dont kwon, this code im get from some web, please how to post photo?

Comment: You do know how to dump a variable?

Comment: Maybe... Why not try it?

Comment: how to get image?
$image = "yeah.jpg";
or
$image = "/path/path/path/yeah.jpg";